# Cannot delist Resource. It is not enlisted for cleanup in the LocalTransactionContainment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I have a singleton Data Access class, which is initialized on the start of the service. I got the QueueConnection from QCF and stored in DataAccess class while initializing(in constructor).

I'm using the same connection for multiple incoming requests(around30 per sec) to send messages to MQ. I get this exception while load testing.

```
WLTC0011E: Cannot delist Resource. It is not enlisted for cleanup in the LocalTransactionContainment.   
J2CA0031I: Method delist caught java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot delist Resource. It is not enlisted for cleanup with this LocalTransactionCoordinator.

J2CA0073E: Unable to delist connection from resource JMS$DBQCF1$JMSManagedConnection@9 from transaction in method localTransactionCommitted due to exception. 
           Initiating destruction of connection. Exception is: javax.resource.ResourceException: delist: caught Exception
```

Here is my code that sends message to queue.

```
public String sendMessage(String reqMsg) throws Exception{
    QueueConnection queueCon = DataAccess.getDataAccess().getQueueCon();
    Queue queue = DataAccess.getDataAccess().getRequestQueue();
    QueueSession session = queueCon.createQueueSession(true,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);
    TextMessage textMsg = queueSession.createTextMessage();

    textMsg.setText(reqMsg);
    sender.send(textMsg);
    String msgId = textMsg.getJMSMessageID();

    queueSession.commit();

    closeSender(sender);
    closeSession(session);

    return msgId;
}
```

I tried to search for this exception but I can't find anything. Can someone tell what it is.? Is it because that i'm using single QueueConnection?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't find exact reason for this issue, but I got around it by tweaking the Create Queue Session parameters.

I changed

`QueueSession session = queueCon.createQueueSession(true,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);`

to

```
QueueSession session = queueCon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

and then removed the commit. After doing this I never saw that exception.

Hope this will help someone who is looking for this exception.